# how to open existing blazor project in vs code

Tags: .net, blazor

Actually i am new in blazor technologies. When I Open my project in vs code it gives error that is mentioned below.

[image: Error]

Any one can guide me how to open existing blazor project i.e .net framework in Vs code.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This does not look like a VS code error, but more a regular VS error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no language service for VS code, so it's advisable to just use the regular VS with the Blazor language extension that gives you the best experience.

That said, if you install the C# extension and the Razor+ extension in VS code, you are able to open Blazor projects in VS Code.